# Why is the community bot closing questions?

Tags: support, closing, exact-duplicates, community-user

[image: Closed 1 hour ago by Penguin and Community.]
Why? I couldn't find anything, I'm just wondering? Does the bot deem that the wording is too similar or something?

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the Community bot...

> Owns the close vote when an asker agrees with a pending duplicate close vote.

- Meta SE FAQ post: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/162827)